# How to plot multiple categorical column values in pandas visualization libraries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Pandas Dataframe which looks like below

|  | test_case | test_type | source_path | table_path | test_status | record_count | table_partition | load_ts | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | check1 | T1 | /documents | /Status | pass | nan | nan | 2021-02-13 19:06:02.527 | 1 |
| 1 | check2 | T1 | /documents | /Status | fail | nan | nan | 2021-02-11 19:06:02.527 | 2 |
| 2 | check3 | T2 | /documents | /Status | pass | nan | nan | 2021-02-12 19:06:02.527 | 3 |
| 3 | check4 | T2 | /documents | /Status | fail | nan | nan | 2021-02-12 19:06:02.527 | 4 |

I want a Plot which tell: For each date(load_ts column),show test_case column values which have passed and test case names which have failed

I have tried the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(15,16))
sns.countplot(x='load_ts', hue="test_status", data=result_df)

plt.show()
```

The problem with this code is that it only shows test status count of pass and fail per date but I also want to see that which test_case names under pass and fail. Kindly see the below plot which I have created as of now.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is the difference between test_case values and test case names? Your plot is showing counts, not labels. Or that is the problem? I might be confused but I'm not sure how or why would you want to plot names, it's more function of a table.

Comment: Test_case like  check1,check2,check3,check should be shown for pass and fail status as in which checks were passed and which checks were failed. I want to see the check names for pass and fail both.

Comment: Where would you like the labels for check1, check2, etc. to be placed? Based on the image you shared, I imagine you would end up with a bunch of labels stacked somewhere near each column which will not make the plot easy to read. Instead, I suggest showing the data in a table with [conditional formatting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Styling).

Comment: @patrick- If I hover over these pass and fail columns,they should be shown.Could you also suggest me the table way ..how can it be shown?

Comment: For labels to be displayed by hovering over the columns you would need to use an interactive plotting library like [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) or [Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/#). Regarding the table approach, I suggest you try the pandas examples shown in the link I shared and look for other questions on SO or other sources if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Tried plotly but it's not working as expected :(